# What value of $\epsilon$ makes $f(x)=1.00$ correct to two place of decimals equivalent to $|f (x)-1|<\epsilon$ where $f(x)=\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$?

Tags: real-analysis

What value of $\epsilon$ makes $f(x)=1.0$ correct to two place of decimals equivalent to $|f (x)-1|<\epsilon$ where $f(x)=\dfrac{\sin(x)}{x}$?
Answer was $\epsilon=0.005$ as answer which is pretty much counterintuitive. Why .005 then? I think I actually didn't get the question. If $f(x)=1.00$ then shouldn't $\epsilon =0.01$? I am confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**remark**

If the exact value is $ f(x)=1.000$, the approximate value should be

$$g(x)=1.001,1.002,1.003,...,1.0099999$$

So, we need
$$|\frac{\sin(x)}{x} - 1| < 0.01$$

In general, the condition $$|g(x)-1|<\epsilon$$
is equivalent to
$$1-\epsilon < g(x) <1+\epsilon$$

Comment: @2Balls1Bat It also depends on the precision of your machine.